# Set ReadOnly to false but still got "ReadOnlyException: Column X is read only"

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am new to C# and maybe similar question were exist but its different.
[image: ReadOnlyException screenshot]

*Component*: `DataGridView`

*Case*: I have a `DataGridView` that is populated from a database using `DataSource`. On the other side I have a `Form` that's used for viewing and editing **a** row of data. After it is successfully updated I want to change a row's data in the `DataGridView` directly - using this code:

```
int rowIndex= 0;
DataGridViewRow row= dtgMasterAsset.Rows[rowIndex];

row.Cells[1].Value = "NEW ASSET NAME"; // ITEM_NAME
row.Cells[2].Value = "NEW CATEGORY NAME"; // ITEM_CATEGORY_NAME
```

In the process, `Cells[1]` is successfully updated but not so with `Cells[2]`. An error message pops up saying:

> *Column ITEM_CATEGORY_NAME is read only*

I try to change the `ITEM_CATEGORY_NAME` column to **`Readonly = false`** in the designer and added a line **`row.Cells[2].Readonly= false;`** just to make it sure AGAIN.

But the error still comes up. Why?
Any explanation?

Thank you.

*FYI: All code is on the same class.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Ashton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2538037/ashton-woods) has pointed out, you could check if `dtgMasterAsset.ReadOnly` is `true`.

However, you stated:

> `Cells[1]` is successfully updated

Therefore, `dtgMasterAsset.ReadOnly` *must* be `false`.  Also, you stated that you tried:

> ```
> row.Cells[2].ReadOnly = false;
> row.Cells[2].Value = "NEW CATEGORY NAME";
> ```

The only way for this to fail is if `row.Cells[2].ReadOnly` is overridden by `dtgMasterAsset.Columns[2].ReadOnly` being `true`.  As the error states, the problem is the column.

---

Despite that you set:

> `ITEM_CATEGORY_NAME` column to `Readonly = false`

I think you should check if `dtgMasterAsset.Columns[2].ReadOnly` is `false` before you set `row.Cells[2].Value` to ensure the column is indeed writable.

My thought is - perhaps your setting in the designer is one (or more) of the following:

1. Not the actual column desired.
2. Not in effect because the column isn't created until binding occurs.
3. Overridden because somewhere in code resets the column to `ReadOnly`.

Comment: i just recheck it again and dtgMasterAsset.ReadOnly is false and is not overridden.

Answer (score 2):

Just found the culprit.

This is how i populate the `DataGridView`

```
String query= "SELECT * FROM VW_ASSET_LIST "; // SQL View 
SqlCommand queryCommand= new SqlCommand(query, connection);

SqlDataReader resultsSet= queryCommand.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dtAsset = new DataTable();
dtAsset.Load(resultsSet);
dtgMasterAsset.DataSource = dtAsset;
```

Somehow the `DataGridView` blocks the system to re-set/set the column that is populated from Aliased SQL Query column ([SQL Table Alias](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)). To fix it just bind the column to another non aliased column.
Other way? i don't know :(

Comment: Glad you found it and shared, that's good to know!  I haven't had the need of Aliased columns in combination with `DataSource` binding.

Answer (score 1):

First check that the whole `DataGridView`'s `ReadOnly` -property is `false`:

`dtgMasterAsset.ReadOnly = false;`

Then check that the used columns' `ReadOnly` -properties are `false`, too.

Comment: DataGridView's property readonly is false, the column readonly is false too

Comment: The `DataGridViewRow`s can be `ReadOnly`, too.

Answer (score 0):

After you have read the data from Datatable, the column which you say its read-only,try to do this :

```
dt.Columns[0].ReadOnly = false;
```

Notice : dt it is your object from the datatable, 0 Number Of your Column in Datatable.

Answer (score -1):

If you fill your `DataGridView` using `SqlDataReader`, it will be read only.
Try to use `SqlDataAdapter`.

Comment: Please provide an example or some explanation in your answer. For additional details, refer to [answer]