# Change ReadOnly property on binded DataGridView

Tags: datagridview

I’ve a DataGridView binded to a dataset wich gets its data from a stored procedure. Column [1] is a fixed value – the last day of current moth: SELECT EOMONTH(GETDATE()) AS periodo. This data grid should provide a template for entries to be saved later after changes and new insertions.
Problem is: this column – only this - is read only, because the fixed value returned by the SP I think.
I Tried to change in the designer, and programmatically, but nope.
Is there a way to change the property to ReadOnly = false, after data in grid is filled?

Comment: A similar question was self-answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30339570/3773066).  As is, aliased columns may always be `ReadOnly`.

Comment: Thank you. I'll experiment by giving an alias to another column of the SP and check if it becomes ReadOnly only.

Comment: If it does, then the only thing I know you can do to solve the issue is make the column non-aliased and manually name the `DataGridViewColumn.HeaderText` to the desired alias name.

Comment: No... alias is not the issue. Gave an alias to another column and it remained editable. It may be the calculated value...

Comment: Solved, I think... Edited the DataSet designer

Comment: private void InitClass() {
                
                this.columnperiodo.ReadOnly = false;
                this.columnvalor.AllowDBNull = false;
                this.columnhistorico.MaxLength = 50;
            }
Of course I think whenever there is a change in the DataSet, automatic generated code will make the column Read only again...